# threejs uv coordinates out of [0-1] range

Tags: three.js, cinema-4d

I create geometry in C4D; export OBJ, then convert using the threejs converter, import into three.js. Then I load in the image file I was using in C4D and it aligns properly; This works as expected.

Occasionally, i get coordinates from the OBJ that are [-1 to 1] instead of [0 to 1]. When this happens, the texture does not display properly (just shows a few pixels scaled up).

QUESTION(s):

- is there a way to consistently get the coords exported into [0-1] scale (I know I can write some normalization code, but it seems like this only occasionally happens so I'd rather just fix the problem than create a workaround) - this may be a Cinema 4D question or general 3D question...
- In three.js is there a way to get UV coords to display correctly if they're [-1 to 1]? I've read about setting .wrapS and .wrapT to THREE.RepeatWrapping but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: To confirm: there is nothing wrong with UV coordinates in the [-1, 1] range, setting the texture wrapping correctly should fix this (by default they are set to *ClampToEdge*. There is of course the chance that your exported coordinates are not only in the [-1, 1] range, but actually -wrong-. Make sure to compare the coordinates before and after the conversion of OBJ to threejs, to pinpoint the source of the error.

Answer (score 1):

What format are you using to upload ThreeJS?
if you have doubts about compiler, you may want to take a look to [ObjLoader Demo](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html)

if values are not between 0 and 1, you should set texture's wrapS and wrapT properties as THREE.RepeatWrapping

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("texture.jpg");
texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.needsUpdate = true; //  if texture is already initialized.
```